# program freezes when processing while loop

Tags: vb.net

I am working in a textbook they want me to use .length, .trim, .remove, .insert, .indexof, .substring, like, is not, and a few others.  i have this program working up til the while loop and it freezes.  **Is there another operator that looks at patterns that will work for what i am trying to do(or is there a way to use like and make this work)?  And if so, how do i use it?**

```
Private Sub btnConvert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConvert.Click

    Dim strWord As String

    strWord = txtBefore.Text

    If strWord.ToUpper.Substring(0, 1) Like "[A,E,I,O,U]" Then
        strWord = strWord.Insert(strWord.Length, "-way")
    ElseIf strWord.ToUpper.Contains("A") Or
        strWord.ToUpper.Contains("E") Or
        strWord.ToUpper.Contains("I") Or
        strWord.ToUpper.Contains("O") Or
        strWord.ToUpper.Contains("U") Then

        strWord = strWord.Insert(strWord.Length, "-")

        'works up until the while loop
        'program freezes no error
        While strWord.ToUpper.Substring(0, 1) IsNot "[A,E,I,O,U,Y]"

            Dim strTemp As String

            strTemp = strWord.Substring(0, 1)
            strWord = strWord.Remove(0, 1)
            strWord = strWord.Insert(strWord.Length, strTemp)
        End While

        strWord = strWord.Insert(strWord.Length, "ay")

    End If

    'txtAfter.Text = strWord
End Sub
```

Comment: thats what im thinking, just tried debugging it still stalls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
While strWord.ToUpper.Substring(0, 1) IsNot "[A,E,I,O,U,Y]"
```

You probably wanted this:

```
While Not {"A","E","I","O","U","Y"}.Contains(strWord.ToUpper.Substring(0, 1))
```

There is no reason to use Regex for such a simple case.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition on the while will always be true.

See details of the IsNot operator here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3bat82c.aspx

The IsNot operator determines if two object references refer to different objects. However, it does not perform value comparisons. If object1 and object2 both refer to the exact same object instance, result is False; if they do not, result is True.

Comment: is their a pattern matching opposite of like i can use?  I didnt realize they were so different.

Comment: I would recommend using RegEx for pattern matching

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
While "AEIOUY".IndexOf(strWord.Substring(0, 1), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
```

The `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` makes it case-insenstive. Using `.ToUpper` is the obvious way to try to do case-insensitive comparisons, but it can cause problems if you ever have to do string comparisons in other cultures. A different StringComparison option could be more suitable.